# How to extract the changesets linked to a workitem in python from tfs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, tfs

I want to extract the changesets and the name of the class affected by the changeset in python using the Microsoft TFS Python Library. https://devopshq.github.io/tfs/index.html

I have connected to TFS using python and am able to retrieve all the required workitems. I want to extract the changesets assosciated with the workitem.

I have used the following code to connect.

```
from tfs import TFSAPI  
user="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"  
password="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth  
client = TFSAPI("https://xyzjds.com", project="abc", user=user,password=password, auth_type=HttpNtlmAuth)    
query = client.run_query('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')    
workitems = query.workitems
```

Now I have all the workitems don't know how to access the changesets of the workitems.

Comment: Please the share the code you tried and where you don't success.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changesets exist in the property `relations` in type `ArtifactLink`, so you should iterate the workitems and check if `relations` exist, if yes check if a relation of type `ArtifactLink` exist, then in the url you get the changeset id:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey. I found the changesets, Thanks alot. Is it possible to know the files changed in the changeset?

Comment: @TasheerHussain Try to use the `client.get_changeset(changeset-id)` method.

Comment: I got that, I wanted the names of the files that were changed in the changeset. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know if its exist in this api, maybe you need to call the changes rest api or another python sdk for tfs.

Comment: Do you know any resource which can be useful and I can look into it?

Comment: Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 and this: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api

Comment: Hi @Shayki . Is it possible to extract all the changesets present under a particular area path? Because some changesets might be submitted without referring to a particular work item.